# Asp.net core 2.1 - Layout controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, model-view-controller, menu

I'm learning asp.net core 2.1. 
I made a database with Menu table ( ID, Name, Actio,Controller) 
And i wanted to pass data from database to menu. 
To do that i need a controller who will pass data to view. How to pass these data to _Layout.cshtml? I will need it for child (partial view "Menu").

In templete mvc there is no controller for Layout...

Comment: You could use help functions to call the controller such as @Html.Action("method", "controller")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it by using ViewComponent

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.1

@Html.Action("Method", "Controller") Doesn't work in Asp.Net CORE 2.1

Answer (score 1):

In the _layout.cshtml you could simply have a

```
@Html.Action("Method", "Controller")
```

in the body which you can use to call another controller. Ideally if this is a navbar etc I'd return a partialView from this method.

Comment: Can't use it in _layout.cshtml for some reason, but I would be awersome it it works ;)

IHtmlHelper<dynamic>' does not contain a definition for 'Action' and the best extension method overload 'UrlHelperExtensions.Action(IUrlHelper, string, object)' requires a receiver of type 'IUrlHelper' [project]

Answer (score 0):

In Core 2.1 You need to use

`<partial name="PartialViewName"/>` instead of `@Html.Action("PartialViewName","ControllerName")`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/partial-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-2.2 See here.